# How to find systemd services that changed on disk?

Tags: systemd, services

Say I have a systemd service called example.service. When I modify that file and then run `systemctl status example.service` I get the following warning:

> **Warning**: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of example.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.

I understand that `systemctl daemon-reload` will make systemd aware of the changes and that `systemctl restart example.service` will stop the service and start it with the new configuration.

How can I get a list of services that have changed on disk and need to be restarted?

As far as I understand, there is no `systemctl list-units --state changed-on-disk`. My next best idea would be a clunky script like this:

```bash
systemctl list-units --type service --no-legend | awk '{ print $1 }' | while read -r service; do
    if systemctl status "$service" -n 0 | grep 'changed on disk' -q; then
        echo "$service
    fi
done
```

However, that only works until someone runs `systemctl daeomon-reload`. After that, the warning is gone and there seems to be no way to detect whether the running service matches the configuration on disk.

Of course I could also just restart everything, but that would cause unnecessary downtime.

So what is the best way to do this?